# The transport failed to connect to the server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have tried almost every thing but can't get this to work. I will appreciate any help. thanks

```
   Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic, System.Net.Mail

   Shared Sub SendMailHTML(ByVal ToAdd, ByVal FromAdd, ByVal Message, ByVal Subject)

    Dim mail As New MailMessage()

    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
    SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxx")
    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    SmtpServer.Port = 465
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
    SmtpServer.Timeout = 5000
    SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network

    Try
        mail.From = New MailAddress("xxxxx@gmail.com")
        mail.To.Add("xxxxxx@gmail.com")

        SmtpServer.Send(Mail)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried sending it over port 25 without SSL?

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the port to 587 for gmail.
 And also add in the try block

```
    mail.Subject= ...
    mail.Body= ...
```

(add suitable strings here)

also try running it without

```
    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
```

I can add my code in C# which works if you need as I do not know VB